# When is the best time to kill a foreground activity?

Tags: android

Okay now here's the question that I can't get rid off unless I have the correct answer for this.I read the Android documentation and walk through some of the interesting links as well but none of them satisfied me. 
 What I can conclude on the basis of my search result is ***The foreground activity, being the most important among the other states, is only killed or terminated as a last resort, especially if it is already consuming too much memory. When a memory paging state has been reach by a foreground activity, then it is killed so that the user interface can retain its responsiveness to the user.***

What I want is just a rigid answer.

Answer (score 2):

If system is low on memory it kills some processes to make some space that operating system can run. So that it starts killing starting from low priority to high (5 to 1). If your foreground activity is destroyed, system has very very low memory to run and even operating system may crash soon.

1. Foreground process
2. Visible process
3. Service process
4. Background process
5. empty process